# Bind Data Of a span to database with ASP MVC,Uses Model Binder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in Asp.net MVC

I need some suggestions for how to make a counter then give the value of it to model binder.

I have two `modal` Pages.in the first one I have this counter for users to choose the number of their request it's like this :
when user click on plus icon the number changed `By Javascript`

[image]

when user  click on next button , the next modal page shows, which I have `selecteddate` and `number of travelers` there by javascript. and also a form which I want model binder to make an object of it.

here is the view of my next modal page in summary

```
<p>
 <span  id="selecteddate"></span>


  <span id="selectedcount"></span>


  <span id="selectedprice"></span>
</p>
```

and here is javascript :

```
$(".nextbtn").click(function () {

$("#selecteddate").html("Selected Date is : "+$("#showdate").html());
$("#selectedprice").html("Total Price is : " + $("#tpriceforall").html());
$("#selectedcount").html($("#shownum").html());
 });
```

and it works correctly.

and also I have a Form in this next modal page too . I want to pass input data of users to data base + the number which is available in `span` `#selectedcount` that `java script set it each time` .

as I want to use `ModelBinder` , there is an input which it would be hidden.
but just to pass data . here is the input for TravelersCount of my Request Model

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.TravelersCount, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.TravelersCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @*@Value=?????*@ } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.TravelersCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
</div>
```

What Should I write for `Value` in the `EditorFor`?

Or if this way is completely irregular please suggest me new one. 
Really appreciate you'r help. thanks

Comment: Your `EditorFor()` method creates an input with `id="Request_TravelersCount"` so you just need `$('#Request_TravelersCount').val($("#selectedcount").text());` to set its value (and never attempt to set the `value` attribute in a `HtmlHelper` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh my god It works :) really thank you. is it possible for you to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditorFor()` method creates an input with `id="Request_TravelersCount"`.

To update its `value` when the button is clicked, you can use

```
$(".nextbtn").click(function () {
    $("#selecteddate").html("Selected Date is : "+$("#showdate").html());
    $("#selectedprice").html("Total Price is : " + $("#tpriceforall").html());
    var num = $("#shownum").html();
    $("#selectedcount").html(num);
    $('#Request_TravelersCount').val(num);
});
```

Side note: You should not attempt to set the value attribute in a `HtmlHelper` method (the method will set the correct value taking into account `ModelState` values)

Comment: Setting Value for html Method is not proper at all every where?

Comment: No, you should never do that. The `HtmlHelper` methods will do it correctly taking to to account the value of the property and/or any values in `ModelState` or the `ViewDataDictionary` if they exist